# Difficulty styling input box for iPhone and iPad

Tags: css, wordpress

I am having a problem styling my search form in my side bar widget. My website is [here](https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk).

I added some additional CSS like this:

```
#is_widget-3 .search-field  {
  width: 70%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px !important;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px !important;
  border-radius: 4px !important;
}

#is_widget-3 .search-submit {
  text-shadow: none;
  font-style: normal;
  background: #d35438 !important;
  color: #000 !important;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 1px white !important;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius:4px;
  -webkit-border-radius:4px;
  border: white 1px solid;
  -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

The button now looks consistent with my other buttons and I am happy with it on my Desktop Browser:

[image: Search Form on PC]

The problem is when it is shown on a handheld device like an iPad:

[image: Search Form on iPad]

I can't work out how to stop the search field from having those rounded corners. I want it to look like my desktop version. Can't work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a mobile Safari "issue". Try adding these CSS rules to the input field:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
border-radius: 0;
```

Comment: That was it! Great. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the css `@media` rule to target tablets and phones.